# Multiple discrete RV convolutions performance

Tags: probability-or-statistics, convolution, discrete

I have a discrete random variable with PDF of (just a simplified example)

```
Piecewise[{{1/3, x == 5 || x == 10 || x == 15}}, 0]
```

Actually, in my code this is a `MixtureDistribution` of a number of discrete distributions.

What I need is to obtain a multiple convolution (for example a 100-fold) of independent identically distributed random variables, distributed according to the provided distribution.

I tried all known to me ways:

1) `TransformedDistribution`

```
TransformedDistribution[Plus @@ Flatten[Table[tX[v], {v, 0, vMax}]], Flatten[Table[tX[v] \[Distributed] resF, {v, 0, vMax}]]]
```

2) multiple `DiscreteConvolve`

```
DiscreteConvolve[PDF[resF, x], PDF[resF, x], x, y]
```

where `resF` is the provided initial distribution.

The first method provides the needed result, but it takes way too long and the time grows exponentially - approx 60 seconds to obtain a ~10-fold convolution, a few minutes for the next.

The second method seem to provide the correct answer for a couple of first convolutions (and it take longer compared to the first method), but the next convolutions give 0.

Just to compare I wrote a simple head-on program on C# to do the task and it takes only ~2-3 second to do the 300-fold convolution. And there is way to optimize it by removing values, higher than the threshold on the go.

Ultimately, I need the probability that the final convolution will be smaller than a provided threshold, i.e. CDF.

Can someone tell me why is it taking so long or if I'm doing this the wrong way.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Some code that I test:

```
ClearAll[resFF, vMax];
AbsoluteTiming[
 resF = EmpiricalDistribution[{1/3, 1/3, 1/3} -> {5, 10, 15}];
 vMax = 10;
 PDF[TransformedDistribution[
   Plus @@ Flatten[Table[tX[v], {v, 1, vMax}]], 
   Flatten[Table[tX[v] \[Distributed] resF, {v, 1, vMax}]]], x]
]
```

Here `resF` is the distribution I mentioned in the beginning, and `vMax` is the number of convolutions I want to obtain. So this code gives the PDF of a 10-fold convolution.

On my machine it takes 3 seconds to do the 10-fold convolution, 8 seconds for 11-fold and 25 seconds for 12-fold. As I need more than 100-fold one, this performance is not sufficient.

**EDIT 2**

As Jim Baldwin said, I missed the fact that I can obtain the result using the generating functions of discrete random variables.

Thus, the code I came up with that gives me the desired value of `vMax`-fold convolution CDF in point `1000` is:

```
ClearAll[resF, gen, vMax];
vMax = 150;
resF[x_] := Piecewise[{{1/3, x == 5 || x == 10 || x == 15}}, 0];
gen = GeneratingFunction[resF[n], n, x];

Total@Select[CoefficientList[(gen)^vMax, x][[1 ;; 1000]], # > 0 &]
```

However, in this case I have to scale the initial data, if the outcomes of RV are not integer.

PS: This is out of my own curiosity, but still - if anyone know why the `TransformedDistribution` solution works so slow, please, tell me. Thanks!

Comment: It will make your question more attractive if you explain your abbreviations.  Please do not create new tags unless it seems clear that there's a benefit (e.g. there are already many questions which could have had the tag) and the name is self explanatory (`rv`??)

Comment: @Szabolcs , yes, you are right. I should expand them. RV stands for random variable.

Comment: Your code makes no sense as you have not defined `tX[v]`, nor `vMax`, nor `resF`. It's just gobbledegook at the moment, leaving the reader to guess.

Comment: You should also give a complete example.  For instance, you give the PDF as a formula and not as a *Mathematica* distribution function.  Also, because you state that these are all identical independent random variables, why not use generating functions?  The generating function of the sum of $n$ random variables is just the generating function of a single random variable raised to the $n$-th power.  You could then use the functions `Coefficient` or `CoefficientList` to get the probabilities of interest.

Comment: @wolfies Provided the code with explanations.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Somehow, I didn't think about this possibility. However, in this case I will have to scale all the possible outcomes of my initial random variable to account for cases when they are non-integer, and to "reverse" it when counting the coefficients. Am I right? If so, then for the provided example works faster then my naive C# code.

Are there any caveats with this solution? For example, if my initial distribution consists of like ~100 outcomes, instead of 3?

And I still would like to know why `TransformedDistribution` is so slow.

Comment: Don't know.  You need to give all of the necessary details such as the size of your actual situation.  If things are slow with n=10 and just 3 outcomes, then fixing things for n=100 and 100 outcomes might become impossible with some solutions.  A small example is great but you also need to indicate the size of your real situation to get appropriate help.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Right, but I encountered this problem with even a small example and didn't know where to go. Will be testing my actual case with your solution and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: One can still use probability generating functions when the values are non-integer or you can use a multinomial distribution which gives you the probabilities for the frequencies of each possible outcome.  If most of the values are integers and only a few are non-integers, then great gains in efficiency are possible.  Again, you'd need to give more details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47614/discussion-between-jim-baldwin-and-andrew-s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probability generating functions might be the way to go.  Here's the pgf (probability generating function) of a single random variable:

```
pgf = t^5/3 + t^10/3 + t^15/3
```

The probability generating function for the sum of `n` independent and identically distributed random variables is

```
pgf^n
```

You can get the probability for any value of the resulting sum (as I assume what you mean by the convolution is that you want the distribution of the sum of the `n` random variables) by using `CoefficientList` and a bit of clean-up:

```
pgf = t^5/3 + t^10/3 + t^15/3;
cl = CoefficientList[pgf^10, t];
x = Range[0, Length[cl] - 1];
pdf = Transpose[{x, cl}];
Select[pdf, #[[2]] > 0 &]]
```

> ```
> {{50, 1/59049}, {55, 10/59049}, {60, 55/59049}, {65, 70/19683}, {70, 
>   205/19683}, {75, 484/19683}, {80, 950/19683}, {85, 1580/19683}, {90,
>    2255/19683}, {95, 8350/59049}, {100, 8953/59049}, {105, 8350/
>   59049}, {110, 2255/19683}, {115, 1580/19683}, {120, 950/
>   19683}, {125, 484/19683}, {130, 205/19683}, {135, 70/19683}, {140, 
>   55/59049}, {145, 10/59049}, {150, 1/59049}}
> ```

As far as timing...Here is an example for `n=100`:

```
Timing[pgf = t^5/3 + t^10/3 + t^15/3;
 cl = CoefficientList[pgf^100, t];
 x = Range[0, Length[cl] - 1];
 pdf = Transpose[{x, cl}];
 Select[pdf, #[[2]] > 0 &];]
(* {0.0312002`,Null} *)
```